# SDL2 How to draw dotted line

Tags: c, sdl-2

Is is just possible to draw a simple dotted line using SDL2 (or with gfx) like

```
int drawDottedLine(SDL_Renderer *renderer,Sint16 x1,Sint16 y1, Sint16 x2, Sint16 y2, int r, int g, int b, int a);
```

found absolutely nothing on the web wtf is it so hard ?

Comment: I dont think SDL has that functionality built in, you would have to implement it yourself

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply implement it yourself ...
Check the "Bresenham algorithm" for draw a line.

For a doted line, it's just many full line, so a pencil and paper with trigonometry should work out :)

Edit : For a dotted line, you even don't have the use to the "Bresenham algorithm", you just need trigonometry.

And by the way, for those who have downvoted, explain yourself ?

Comment: I think that a custom Bresenham algorithm is more appropriate than a trig approach because trig requires floating point math where Bresenham doesn't.  Add a counter to the Bresenham algo just at the point where it sets the pixel colour.  For each new coordinate on the path increment the counter, If the counter is (say) 5 then toggle a boolean flag and reset the counter.  Only draw the pixels when the flag is true.

Comment: If you want an optimised function, yes, a custom Bresenham is the way, if you just want a doted line, one "cos", one "sin" and the function is nearly finished.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working function, that uses the Bresenham algorithm:

```
void DrawDottedLine(SDL_Renderer* renderer, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {
    int dx =  abs(x1-x0), sx = x0<x1 ? 1 : -1;
    int dy = -abs(y1-y0), sy = y0<y1 ? 1 : -1;
    int err = dx+dy, e2;
    int count = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (count < 10) {SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer,x0,y0);}
        if (x0==x1 && y0==y1) break;
        e2 = 2*err;
        if (e2 > dy) { err += dy; x0 += sx; }
        if (e2 < dx) { err += dx; y0 += sy; }
        count = (count + 1) % 20;
    }
}
```

You must consider that this function has terrible performance, because every point of the dashed line will call `SDL_RenderDrawPoint()` in order to get rendered.

Comment: Well, you could buffer the points up & draw them all in one go via `SDL_RenderDrawPoints()`, should be less slow :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used for my pong game:

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 155, 155, 155, 255);
for (line.y = 0; line.y < WINDOW_HEIGHT; line.y += 10)
{
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &line);
}
```

Earlier in the code I initialized the line:

```
SDL_Rect line;
line.w = 2;
line.h = 8;
line.x = WINDOW_WIDTH / 2;
```